# Java Servlet with Multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I am trying to create multiple output text data files based on the data present in the servlet request. The constraints to my servlet are that:

- My servlet waits for enough requests to hit a threshold (for example 20 names in a file) before producing a file
- Otherwise it will timeout after a minute and produce a file

The code I have written is such that:

1. `doGet` is not synchronized
2. Within `doGet` I am creating a new thread pool (reason being that the calling application to my servlet would not send a next request until my servlet returns a response back - so I validate the request and return an instant acknowledgement back to get new requests)
3. Pass over all request data to the thread created in a new thread pool
4. Invoke synchronized function to do thread counting and file printing

I am using `wait(60000)`. The problem is that the code produces files with correct threshold (of names) within a minute, but after the timeout of a minute, the files produced (a very few) have capacity exceeded for example, names more than what I have defined in the capacity.

I think it has something to do with the threads who when wake up are causing an issue?

My code is

```
if(!hashmap_dob.containsKey(key)){
request_count=0;
hashmap_count.put(key, Integer.toString(request_count));

sb1 = new StringBuilder();
sb2 = new StringBuilder();
sb3 = new StringBuilder();

hashmap_dob.put(key, sb1);
hashmap_firstname.put(key, sb2);    
hashmap_surname.put(key, sb3);
                }

if(hashmap_dob.containsKey(key)){
    request_count = Integer.parseInt(hm_count.get(key));
    request_count++;
    hashmap_count.put(key, Integer.toString(request_count));
    hashmap_filehasbeenprinted.put(key, Boolean.toString(fileHasBeenPrinted));  
                }


          hashmap_dob.get(key).append(dateofbirth + "-");
    hashmap_firstname.get(key).append(firstName + "-");
    hashmap_surname.get(key).append(surname + "-");


    if (hashmap_count.get(key).equals(capacity)){

        request_count = 0; 

    dob = hashmap_dob.get(key).toString();
    firstname = hashmap_firstname.get(key).toString();
    surname = hashmap_surname.get(key).toString();

    produceFile(required String parameters for file printing);

    fileHasBeenPrinted = true;
    sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    sb3 = new StringBuilder();

    hashmap_dob.put(key, sb1);
    hashmap_firstname.put(key, sb2);
    hashmap_surname.put(key, sb3);
    hashmap_count.put(key, Integer.toString(request_count));
    hashmap_filehasbeenprinted.put(key, Boolean.toString(fileHasBeenPrinted));
            }
    try{

    wait(Long.parseLong(listenerWaitingTime)); 


        }catch (InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println("Thread interrupted from wait");
            }

    if(hashmap_filehasbeenprinted.get(key).equals("false")){

    dob = hashmap_dob.get(key).toString();
    firstname = hashmap_firstname.get(key).toString();
    surname = hm_surname.get(key).toString();

    produceFile(required String parameters for file printing );

    sb1 = new StringBuilder();  
    sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    sb3 = new StringBuilder();
    hashmap_dob.put(key, sb1);
    hashmap_firstname.put(key, sb2);
    hashmap_surname.put(key, sb3);
    fileHasBeenPrinted= true;
    request_count =0;
    hashmap_filehasbeenprinted.put(key, Boolean.toString(fileHasBeenPrinted));

    hashmap_count.put(key, Integer.toString(request_count));
            }
```

If you have got to here, then thank you for reading my question and thanks in advance if you have any thougths on it towards resolution!

Comment: FYI - Camel casing is the generally accepted naming convention for Java variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Robin

Answer (score 4):

I didn't look at your code but I find your approach pretty complicated. Try this instead:

1. Create a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for the data to work on.
2. In the servlet, put the data into a queue and return.
3. Create a single worker thread at startup which pulls data from the queue with a timeout of 60 seconds and collects them in a list.
4. If the list has enough elements or when a timeout occurs, write a new file.

Create the thread and the queue in a `ServletContextListener`. Interrupt the thread to stop it. In the thread, flush the last remaining items to the file when you receive an `InterruptedException` while waiting on the queue.

Comment: Nice approach. But this will require additional background thread to run to monitor BLOCKING_QUEUE. Servlet will exit once request is completed. Then how do you suggest to do monitor and act on BlockingQueue with in Web Application itself.

Comment: Create the thread + queue in a `ServletContextListener`. That way, you can also cleanly stop the thread.

Comment: My guess is that he is writing his own server, so he won't use Java EE and ServletContextListener.  But I do think he should use a BlockingQueue and a worker thread(s).

Comment: I am using Jave EE with Tomcat and I agree that ArrayBlockingQueue might have the right solution. So now I would try that but thanks guys for your precious comments.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to create/produce a new file in two situations:

- Number of request hit a predefined threshold.
- Threshold time-out completes.

I would suggest following:

1. Use APPLICATION-SCOPED variable: requestMap containing object of HttpServletRequest.
2. On every servlet hit, just add the received request to map.
3. Now create listener/filter requestMonitor whatever is suitable, to monitor values of requestMap.
4. RequestMonitor should check if the requestMap has grown to predefined threshold.
5. If it has not, then it should allow servlet to add request object.
6. If it has, then it should print file, empty requestMap, then allow Servlet to add next request.
7. For timeout, you can check when the last file was produced  with LAST_FILE_PRODUCED variable in APPLICATION_SCOPE. This should be updated every time file is produced.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to read your code, but there is a lot of information missing, so if you could please give more details:

1)  the indentation is messed up and I'm not sure if there were some mistakes introduced when you copied your code.

2) What is the code you are posting?  The code that is called on some other thread after by doGet?

3) Maybe you could also add the variable declarations.  Are those thread safe types (ConcurrentHashMap)?

4) I'm not sure we have all the information about fileHasBeenPrinted.  Also it seems to be a Boolean, which is not thread safe.

5) you talk about "synchronized" functions, but you did not include those.

**EDIT**:

If the code you copied is a synchronized method, that means if you have many requests, only one of them only ever runs at a given time.  The 60 seconds waiting is always invoked it seems (it is not quite clear with the indentation, but I think there is always a 60 seconds wait, whether the file is written or not).  So you lock the synchronized method for 60 seconds before another thread (request) can be processed.  That could explain why you are not writing the file after 20 requests, since more than 20 requests can arrive within 60 seconds.

Comment: 1 - I manually tried to indent it and had changed the variable names from original code due to data sensitivity. Clearly my indentation has not worked otu well so sorry about that.

Comment: 2 - this is a code within my synchronized method where I count the threshold and then print the file. This method is called from doGet. However as I explained earlier, I have created a new pool of threads from doGet and from that pool thread this method is being invoked.

Comment: 3 - As the code posted is within a synchronized method but I have initiated my hashmaps at global level. I am not using ConcurrentHashMaps, is this something which would be causing a problem. Please note that I only make changes to the Hashmaps within sysnchronized method so I believe using concurrentHashmap would not make any difference?

Comment: 4 - You are correct about fileHasBeenPrinted being boolean. Again I agree it's not thread safe but because any changes I make to fileHasBeenPrinted are within sysnchronized method (only declaration at global level), I think it would not be an issue but again I might be wrong. Please let me know your thoughts!

Comment: 5 - I hope this has now been answered as the code is an extract from the synchronized method. Just to give more information, the produceFile method within the extract is also synchronized. thanks

Comment: Also I wanted hashmaps keys i.e. the string buffer where i append the data & my threshold counter to be modified by each thread entering the sysnchronized method.

Comment: Reply to EDIT: You are absolutely correct in saying everyrequest waiting 60 seconds but not the one which would hit the threshold. This is how I have the requirements for design. Please note that the files are produced as per the threshold. The problem is only with files which get produced after the timeout of a minute.